# Creating a 301 Redirect Does Not Want to Work

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am trying to create a 301 redirect to move from one system to another. I have the process nailed down that matches the old url to the new url and generates all the 301s for me but for the life of me I cannot get .htaccess to get the redirect to fire.

I have a feeling that it has to do with the fact that I have to use a query string in order to go between the two systems. Anyways here is what I have in my .htaccess file now:

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymLinks

redirect 301 /cgi-bin/classifieds/classifieds.cgi?db=autos&website=FossilCars&language=&session_key=&search_and_display_db_button=on&results_format=long&db_id=46990&query=retrieval http://domain.com/triumph/tr6/46990
```

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong here? I have already disabled the cgi-bin directory in my Apache configuration (I know that because it's now loading our custom 404 page instead of the generic one).

Thanks

Josh Pennington

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Apache does not use the query string when determining a match for a URL redirect. The answer is to set a URL rewrite. Here is an example that worked for me:

```
# Redirect From 
# /cgi-bin/classifieds/classifieds.cgi?db=autos&website=FossilCars&language=&session_key=&search_and_display_db_button=on&results_format=long&db_id=46990&query=retrieval
# To
# /triumph/tr6/46990
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /cgi-bin/classifieds/classifieds.cgi$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^db=autos&website=FossilCars&language=&session_key=&search_and_display_db_button=on&results_format=long&db_id=46990&query=retrieval$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com/triumph/tr6/46990? [L,R=301]
```

The ? at the end of the RewriteRule line drops the query string from the redirected URL.